# VB 2010 mkdir read only

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, security, mkdir

Hi i cant seem to get mkdir to create a folder which isnt read only, this is causing alot of problems in my code because i am unable to write files to the directory i have created. thanks for any help. this is my code below:

```
Else

    MessageBox.Show("Please set a Root Path for your ****")
    RootFBD.ShowDialog()
    TextBox1.Text = RootFBD.SelectedPath
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\****-Tools\config\root.txt")
 End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f2 As New FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, TextBox1.Text)
    f2.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write Or FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, TextBox1.Text)

    Dim rootSave As System.IO.StreamWriter
    rootSave = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\****-Tools\config\root.txt", True)
    rootSave.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
    Me.Hide()
    MainTool.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks again josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the problem; this isn't a permission issue.
Rather, you're leaving the file open, which prevents other processes from writing to ir.

You just need to `Close()` your `StreamWriter`.

Or, you can just call `File.AppendText`, which will avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the directory with the file name.  Try this:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\****-Tools\config")
```